# How do you specify a human-readable localhost url (i.e. localhost/loremipsum) for a local web app using Docker Desktop for Windows?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I'm just starting out with Docker for the first time as a replacement for XAMPP. All I'm doing is hosting a local instance of WordPress (and an associated MySQL database) on my (Win 11) laptop to use as a personal journal. I installed Docker Desktop and followed [these instructions](https://developer.yoast.com/blog/set-up-wordpress-development-environment-in-docker/) to create a compose file to install and run my WordPress instance. It worked fine, and when the image(?) is running, I can view my WordPress instance at localhost in a browser.

Before doing that, I tried out the docker tutorial, and I noticed that it forwarded to localhost/tutorial. I'd like to replicate that. How can I get my WordPress instance to map to something like localhost/example instead of just localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Docker does not have routing based on path, this is up to your web server to configure different paths for root page (or root directory as WP calls it). That said it is basically a common change on wordpress URL Site URL if you want to as well the files location.

Here is the docs from WP on how to do it https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#method-ii-with-url-change. I'm going to rewrite just the steps that will change since you are using docker-compose that you created following the wordpress development environment article

1 - Create the new location for the core WordPress files to be stored (we will use `/example` in our examples). (On your Windows 11 create a new folder named `example` under `./wordpress`)

2 - In WordPress address (URL): set the address of your main WordPress core files. Example: `http://localhost/example`

3 - In Site address (URL): set root directory’s URL. Example: `http://localhost/example`

8 - Open your root directory’s `./wordpress/index.php` file in a text editor

9 - Change the following and save the file. Change the line that says: `require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';` to the following, using your directory name for the WordPress core files `require __DIR__ . '/example/wp-blog-header.php';`

10 - Login to the new location. It might now be `http://localhost/example/wp-admin`

**Step 3 is optional**, in case you want to change your site address as well. The rest of the steps are the same from the WP documentation, please follow that.

Now you can access WP or you site using `http://localhost/example`